# How to consume messages from a specific partition of a topic in kafka

Tags: c, apache-kafka, partition, consumer, librdkafka

I want a kafka consumer to consume messages from a **particular/specified partition** of a topic

It works using **kafka-console-consumer.sh** with switch **--partition partition_number**

I am using **kafka_complex_consumer_example.c** code from **librdkafka**

Upon static code analysis, I feel it can serve my purpose but I am not able to find out the exact command line parameters to be passed to main(int argc & char **argv) function for the code to run and start consuming on a topic's particular partition.

[Have a look at the code here - rdkafka_complex_consumer_example.c](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_complex_consumer_example.c)

[Full github code of librdkafka here FYR](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka)

If this code doesn't serve the purpose, please specify some other code that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the usage string, putting a colon after the topic name designates which partition to consume from

More specifically, topicpartition type holds information for a specific partition, and this line creates the list of those

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_complex_consumer_example.c#L528

Comment: Topic:Partition solved my problem. Mention Colon(:) between the two with no spaces. Thanks @OneCricketer

Comment: Feel free to use the checkmark next to the answer to accept it